# AJAX request is empty on receipt

Tags: python, ajax, post, flask

I might be doing something silly here, but for some reason, what seems to be a perfectly valid ajax request to me isn't working.

This is the AJAX request:

```
data = {emotions: lRes};
console.log(data); //Data seems to be exactly what I'm looking for
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: document.location.origin + "/facedata/" + slug,
    success: function(){
        console.log("Success!");
    }
});
```

But then on the receiving end of the AJAX request:

```
@app.route('/facedata/<slug>', methods=["POST"])
def facedata(slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get_or_404(slug=slug)
            print request.args
            sys.stdout.flush()
            data = request.args.get("emotions")
            post.face_data.append(data)
            post.save()
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

When I log args, I just get an empty `ImmutableMultiDict` Object, so the emotions call is still failing. Does anybody know what exactly is going on here?

Comment: @JonClements I feel so very silly, but thank you so much for answering this question. Could you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.args` is the parameters supplied in the URL. Flask's `request` objects contain a `.form` attribute that contains POSTed data - so you'll have to use `request.form` to access the data sent via your AJAX request, eg:

```
@app.route('/facedata/<slug>', methods=["POST"])
def facedata(slug):
    emotions = request.form.get('emotions')
```